# MatLab - gradient command

Tags: matlab, gradient

I am trying to learn various functions and commands in MatLab.  I have a question regarding the `gradient` command.

Say I define the following:

```
x = 0:1:10;

f = @(x) x.^2 + 2*x -1;

h = gradient(f(x))
```

This then gives me the following vector:

```
h =  3     4     6     8    10    12    14    16    18    20    21
```

I see that the values are correct when x is between 1 and 9, but this is incorrect for x = 0 and x = 10.  When x = 0, the gradient should be 2, and when x = 10, the gradient should be 22.  So why does MatLab give erroneous answers for these two input values?

If anyone could explain this to me I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the result is correct. When

```
>> x0 = 0
>> f(x0) 
    -1
```

such that the gradient is indeed 3. Similarly for `x=10`, as `f(10) = 119` and `f(9)=98`, so the gradient is indeed = 21.

The discrepancy between these results and the analytical result is because the gradient is a numerical approximation to the derivative with associated *boundary issues*.

Consider further what would have happened if you had given less data points, say only two points - the algorithm would give you the gradient as the difference between the points divided by the interval. This is what is happening at the boundary.

Comment: Well, but the derivative of the function is f'(x) = 2*x +2.  So f'(0) = 2.  This is the change in direction along the x-direction.

Comment: But the derivative is not the same as the numerical gradient!

Comment: On the MathWorks website explaining the gradient command it says:  "FX = gradient(F) where F is a vector returns the one-dimensional numerical gradient of F. FX corresponds to ∂F/∂x, the differences in x (horizontal) direction."  So since ∂F/∂x = 2*x + 2, I must admit that I still don't understand where the values 3 and 21 come from.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it now.  The gradient is only calculated as an approximation based on the interval I've specified, is that right?  So if I had x-values closer together, the values would have been more correct?

Comment: Actually the first thing the help page on gradient says is `GRADIENT Approximate gradient`.

Comment: Yep you got it - perfect. For example, you could have the same function. But if you give it two input points, 0, 1, how is it supposed to determine a meaningful gradient from two y-points...

Comment: Great!  Thanks a lot :).  Still a novice with MatLab, and sometimes I forget that we are dealing with approximations.  Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking at a [boundary problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_problem_%28spatial_analysis%29). Expand `x` and you'll get the right answer. Remember that you are performing a numerical calculation

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, I got it now :).  Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

The `help gradient` command doesn't provide enough details of its implementation.

But if you type in **`edit gradient`**, it will show you the `m`-file source code `gradient.m`, where you can see how it is calculated:

- One-sided differences at the ends of the array.
- Centred-differences for all other points.

(You can do better by using higher-accuracy stencils. Especially you may want to use a second-order-accurate stencil for the items on the ends, for consistency with the second-order accurate centred-differences.)